# Como receber uma notificacao no android sempre que houver um registro em uma tabela?

Tags: android

Estou com um problema, tenho um projeto android que preciso receber uma notificação no celular sempre que houver um novo cliente no banco de dados(em background também!). mas o problema eh que não encontro uma forma de saber quando houver uma mudança no banco de dados!

Estou usando um banco de dados externo MYSQL e puxando as informações via json direto em uma listview(se quiserem posto o código aqui.).

alguém teria uma ideia de como posso fazer pra ser notificado no celular quando houver um novo cliente no banco de dados ??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você pode usar *push notifications* (GCM no caso do Android).

Primeiramente [estude o GCM](https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/gcm).

No momento em que você adicionar um novo registro no banco, dispare uma solicitação de envio de *push notification* ao servidor do GCM. Isso pode ser feito via uma *trigger* no banco ou de alguma outra forma.

Quando o *push* chegar ao celular, solicite ao servidor os novos dados.

Comment: obrigado pela ideia, vou dar uma olhada !

Comment: Ok. Caso a resposta atenda a sua necessidade, faça assim para aceitá-la: http://i.stack.imgur.com/uqJeW.png